# Slack Event API - User Mentions

Tags: events, slack, slack-api

I see that there is a way to subscribe only for [app mentions](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention).

But I'm looking for subscribing for those message only, in which 1 or more user is mentioned instead. (For users who have authorized my app, or maybe all users is fine too.) As a user I can mention others in multiple different types of conversations. Hence, today I'm subscribing to  [message.channels](https://api.slack.com/events/message.channels), [message.groups](https://api.slack.com/events/message.groups), [message.im](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) and [message.mpim](https://api.slack.com/events/message.mpim)

This leads to processing of a lot of messages!
For example, I need to process each and every message that gets posted in channels.

Comment: To my knowledge their are only `app_mentions`.

Comment: Hmm., Do you know if I can configure it to post in bulk ? Maybe something like post for every 50 msges or once for every 5mins.

Comment: If you mean on the Slack API side: no, you can't. But why not implement that feature in your app, which you have full control over?

Comment: did you have any luck with this @ShreeHarshaS ??

Comment: @JVLobo Not yet. As far as I understand i have to listen for all messages in my app and process it, can't do this in an efficient way by listening only for user mentions.